# how can I convert a game sensitivity to my Unreal Engine project sensitivity?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to make an aim-based project. Anyways I can convert a valorant, cs go, R6S, warface and all the other aim-based games sensitivity to an UE5 sensitivity? I've checked all the possible sensitivity converting sites but none of those had a posibility to convert a sens into an Unreal Engine project.

Comment: Please [edit] your question - see *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)* . Also, for non-programming related questions, use https://gamedev.stackexchange.com - check the [help site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/) in order to know if your question is on-topic there.

Comment: Dear OP, i am reviewer, take the tour,see guidelines and also see how to ask questions here, and become familiar with site.